# OCaml - prefix all strings in a Set

Tags: string, functional-programming, set, ocaml

I'm using the Set module in OCaml to create Sets of Strings.

I'm struggling on how to prefix a given string onto all elements of the set of strings.

Would I be on the right lines using Set.iter or Set.elements?

Comment: Use `Set.Map` : http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Set.Make.html#VALmap

Comment: Also, notice that `Set`-s are **immutable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set.map` is what you're looking for. It applies a given function to all elements of a Set and return the Set containing the results.

```
module StringSet = Set.Make(String);;

let new_set = 
  let set = StringSet.of_list ["a";"b";"c"] in
  StringSet.map (fun s -> "prefix_"^s) set (* This is the important line *)
;;

(* Checking the contents of `new_set` *)
StringSet.elements new_set;;
```

The last expression will give the following:

```
- : string list = ["prefix_a"; "prefix_b"; "prefix_c"]
```

Comment: Don't give an answer if no work is provided. He actually didn't ask for an answer but if he was going in the right direction.

Comment: I see it more like an example. There are still things to do to make a full implementation : make the prefix generic, include this function in the `StringSet` module, and so on.

Comment: Well, this looks clearly like a homework (I see the question : "Given a Set of strings, create a function which returns a new set containing all the strings prefixed with a string s") and your "example" is the perfect answer. If you look at his history, I'd say his Ocaml course started not so long ago and whenever he has a problem he comes here to ask. I may be wrong but it still bothers me when people answers without asking for a minimal work done.

Comment: To add to my rant, I suggest you read this : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions.